# How to obtain memory address of string literal?

Tags: windows, binary-analysis, amd64

I am trying to find where a specific string literal is used in a compiled program. I have already found the location of this string literal within the executable; I want to somehow deduce what the memory address of this string will be at runtime, so I can search the binary file for this address to find the instruction that references the string. How should I proceed?

I am using a Windows x64 AMD architecture. The executable in question is also 64-bit.

Comment: You may try this Strings tool from sysinternals: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings

Comment: Thanks, but I have already found the location of the string within the executable file; I'm asking for a way to find the runtime memory address, since I think that is different from the byte offset in the actual file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OllyDbg software (http://www.ollydbg.de/). This software is for debug and dissasembler binary programs.

One of feature is search all referenced string, you can see this image:

[image: OllyDbg search all referenced strings]

So, in the next window, you can see all strings with an address. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Apparently this only works with 32-bit executables, while the executable in question is 64-bit. (I tried loading it, it didn't work.) Probably should edit my question to clarify that. Is there an equivalent piece of software that works for 64-bit executables?

Comment: There is x64dbg thwt works on windowsx64. Olydbg does have a x64 version , but Oleh isn't really active in it's development , so It's sort of in a dead state.

Answer (score 0):

Search for all string references and you should be able to find your string and go to the instruction referencing it from there.

Comment: ....but how exactly do I search for all string references? Do I need to install some specific software?

Comment: Yes, ollydbg, like incode said can do the job. You have a lot of disassemblers, the best is probably IDA (free and premium version).